# Set variable in the JOIN condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I assign a value to the variable in the JOIN condition?

```
declare @t1 table(id int);
declare @t2 table(id int);
declare @var int;
select *
from @t2 t2
left outer join @t1 t1 on (t1.id = t2.id); --I wanna assign 5 to @var if condition on is true
```

Comment: You'll need to join it to something regardless... what happens if the condition is false?

Comment: `case` statement. But put up some sample input, or full query, or atleast scenario to get better answer

Comment: As is, your question lacks content. Please provide at least the structure of the tables involved, the condition you want and the `ON` clause for when the condition evaluates to `true` and when it evaluates to `false`.

Comment: you may use `LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 t1 ON @var1 = @var2`

Comment: Question is far too vague, please clarify with scenarios, or intents at least

Comment: I wanted to change the variable used value from t2 if my condition t1.id=t2.id is true

Comment: Again. Please [edit] your question to provide some more details.

Comment: `// bad: non-trivial destructor
<br>const std::string kFoo = "foo";`

Answer (score -1):

This question seems unnecessarily abstract. It would help to have more details of the business goal.

Here is one way, but bear in mind that this will set the value of @var for every row processed, and you end up with the "last" row deciding the value. If there are only ever 1 row in each of @t1 and @t2, then this form will work. However, there may be a better way, which I included below.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id INT);
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT);
DECLARE @var INT;
SELECT
    @var =
    CASE
        WHEN @t1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 5 --Outer table match found, so set @var
        ELSE NULL --Put whatever you want here for the default value
    END
FROM
    @t2 t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @t1 t1 ON
        (t1.id = t2.id); --I wanna assign 5 to @var if condition on is true
```

If all you care about is that there is AT LEAST one match, and there may be more than 1 row in either table, then do this. It may represent your intent more accurately.

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE(id INT);
DECLARE @t2 TABLE(id INT);
DECLARE @var INT;

IF EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM @t1 INNER JOIN @t2 ON @t1.id = @t2.id
    )
    BEGIN
        SET @var = 5
    END
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know if I could make a request without extra join.
We know if contract exists then it has partner. I had to write
`left outer join ccContract    co on (co.ContractID  = w.ContractID)
left outer join ccPartner      v on (co.PartnerID  = v.PartnerID)`
But I wanted something like this
`left outer join ccContract  co on (co.ContractID  = w.ContractID and @hasPartner = 1)` and use @hasPartner in select statement
Is it real? (similar to check expressions with && in c++, if left operand is true go right operand)

Comment: @AlexanderMordovskiy If you don't want the extra JOIN, you can use a correlated subquery like "LEFT JOIN ccContract AS co ON co.ContractID = w.ContractID AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ccPartner v WHERE v.PartnerID = co.PartnerID). Make sense? This helps especially if the join causes additional rows to be returned for some reason, and all you care about is the existence.

Comment: I see you. But have I opportunity to set variable into ON scope?

Comment: Why do you want to set a variable? Is it enough to emit the column from the SELECT? Variables are scalar, so they have no relevance to sets. Does this query return more than one row, or only 1 row? Do all Contracts have Partner, or only some? Your comment above said "We know if contract exists then it has partner." That implies that all Contracts have Partner, so if your JOIN returns a Contract, then hasPartner is automatically true.

Comment: I was wrong. I meant `left outer join ccContract co on (co.ContractID = w.ContractID and set @hasPartner = 1)` OK. My example is confuses. ccConctract has name. I wanna set @name. ContractID primary key, w.ContractID can be null. I want `left outer join ccContract co on (co.ContractID = w.ContractID and select @name = co.Name)` but if co.ContractID <> w.ContractID select @name = '' . I want to know CAN I SET VARIABLE . I know that correct sol is SELECT co.Name, but please say me is possible set var in condition or not. Thank you)

Comment: No, you cannot perform a variable assignment as part of the JOIN criteria in the ON clause. However, you can just look at the OUTCOME of the JOIN, and use that outcome as leverage to assign your variable, as I did in my answer above. I still don't understand why assigning the variable in the ON clause is any better than doing it in the SELECT. The net result is that a value ends up in the variable, and the SELECT clause is the place to do such things. Let me know if I can help more!